# Eyes not following head even even if the eye bones are parented to the head bone

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

[image]

[image]

I guess the images explain everything.

The eyes are parented to the eye rig bones so that they rotate freely if the eye bones are rotated. The eye bones are parented to the head bone.

How can I solve this issue?

https://pasteall.org/media/a/e/ae654d3ced8f57dc8ed5afb639eff4e5.blend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your eyes cumulate both a classic parentage to their bone and a parentage through *Armature* modifier, you need to choose either one or the other (either remove the parenting or the modifier):

[image]

[image]